# Connect Wakanda Db to BI platform LogiAnalytics

Tags: database, business-intelligence, dashboard, wakanda

Is it possible to connect the Wakanda DB to the BI platforms LogiAnalytics or QlickView ?
What kind of Wakanda connector do we need ?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the REST Api of wakanda DB, and make your own module/connector,
so from any platform from which you can do http calls, you can make direct calls to wakanda DB, but don't forget to secure your wakanda db :)
but personally i prefer the pro connector (with mysql) :)

Answer (score 1):

Wakanda can connect to any database of your choice, you need just the connector pro in Enterprise Edition and then configure it to connect to your BI platform (I mean here the BI's database it can be Mysql, MSSQL, ... etc).

When you get your data model you have so full access to your BI platform as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to do this is to export your data as JSON or SQL.
[exportAsSQL](http://livedoc.wakanda.org/Datastore/Entity-Collection/exportAsSQL.301-1041494.en.html) and [exportAsJSON](http://livedoc.wakanda.org/Datastore/Entity-Collection/exportAsJSON.301-1041820.en.html)

Comment: That should be the case if Wakanda also exports the calculated attributies. This is unfortunately not the case of this nice feature in Wakanda.